# Check if audio link is valid using python requests without loading content

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a database of songs and their corresponding links to the mp3/flac on internet archive (ex. https://ia804601.us.archive.org/0/items/gd1971-04-27.sbd.bode-hoffman-merryprankster-stundel.2998.shnf/gd71-04-27d2t07.mp3). Many of these are bad links so I created a method to iterate through the list and perform a get using requests, checking for a 403. This works well, but whenever the link is valid, the request takes a while depending on the song length.

Is there a way I can quickly see if the link is valid rather than making the full request for the mp3/flac?

Comment: This is what the HEAD HTTP verb is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [stdunbar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2933977/stdunbar) mentioned, the correct verb is HEAD. Requests has a method for this, and that along with the `allow_redirects=True` flag resolved the issue. Thanks!

`r = requests.head(song['url'], allow_redirects=True)`